# bower install bootstrap - error

Tags: npm, bower

I am trying to use bower to install bootstrap. I am getting an error and have no idea what it means.

```
Error: ENOTDIR, mkdir '/var/folders/f2/b3mwhtgd5bqgbk51jpf9z_zh0000gn/T/thomasjanszen/bower'
    at Error (native)
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: What command did you use to install bootstrap with bower? In what folder where you when you run that command?

Comment: bower install bootstrap --save and my examples directory. Within examples I have a public folder, views folder, and bower.json, packages.json, server.js

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1171

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to path where you installed `npm` and `bower` at first time,try to run the command again,worked for me!